# Chai rejectedWith doesn't chain properly

Tags: javascript, chai-as-promised

I have read numerous posts and docs and cannot seem to figure out why this code doesn't work as I think it should.

```
const chai = require('chai');
const expect = chai.expect;
const chaiAsPromised = require('chai-as-promised');
chai.use(chaiAsPromised);

async function foo(val) {

    if (!val) {
        const err = new Error();
        err.status = 404;
        throw err;
    }

    return new Promise(resolve => sleepSetTimeout_ctrl = setTimeout(resolve, 10));
}

describe('does not work', () => {
    it('throws', async () => {
        await expect(foo()).to.be.rejectedWith(Error).and.have.property('status');
    });
});
```

If I end the expect at `rejectedWith(Error)` it works fine, but trying to test that the property exists fails with:
`AssertionError: expected {} to have property 'status'`

Comment: What's the specific failure?

Comment: Updated question with the failure.

Answer (score 1):

This happens because the return value from `rejectedWith` is a `PromisedAssertion` - you're asserting on whether the *promise*(-like object) has a `status` property. I actually get a slightly more helpful message which makes this clearer:

```
AssertionError: expected Promise{…} to have property 'status'
```

You can also see that if you test for a property it does have, like `then`:

```js
await expect(foo()).to.be.rejectedWith(Error).and.have.property('then');  // ✅
```

To assert on the actual error object, you need to use `chai-as-promised`'s chainers again, e.g.:

```js
await expect(foo()).to.be.rejectedWith(Error).and.eventually.have.property("status");  // ✅
                                              // ^---------^
```

As an alternative, particularly if you have multiple assertions to make on the resolved/rejected value, just chain using `.then`:

```js
await expect(foo()).to.be.rejectedWith(Error).then((err) => {
  expect(err).to.have.property("status", 404);
}); // ✅
```

Comment: Thanks!  I have been pulling my hair out on this for quite a while.